# Session is not working in php

Tags: php

I have a page(page_1.php) which has below code..

```
<?php

session_start();

error_reporting(1);

$_SESSION['CHECK']='Test...';

?>
```

and my other page is containing (page_2.php)

```
<?php

session_start();

error_reporting(1);

echo $_SESSION['CHECK'];

?>
```

But i am not getting session result
.I am getting blank screen.What is the problem ?

Comment: your open tags should read <?php, but that's probably a typo... This could have many different reasons, depending on the server settings. Try using phpinfo() to get some more info about your server.

Comment: < php - is it misprint? must be <?php

Comment: The output of phpinfo() has a section about sessions, make sure sessions are enabled and that the save path is a writeable location.

Comment: i wrote <? and space in php because here editor(stackoverflow) was not taking.What i should check in php_info()?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either pass the session_id as a Get?Post parameter, or as a cookie. [See http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to debug anything, it would be helpful if you use another level for error_reporting, for example 2047.(and use it before session_start() )

**What further informations we need:**
How did you keep the sessions alive?
check out the settings for **session.use_cookies** , **session.use_only_cookies**, **session.use_trans_sid**.

Be sure that in page_2.php nothing is before the first starting `<?php` -tag.
If page_2.php is encoded in UTFn , be sure that it doesn't contain a BOM.